# GWT RPC scope issue

Tags: gwt, rpc, gwt-rpc

I'm having a problem saving the result of a RPC. Basically the call is successful but when I try to save it in a variable it seems to go out of scope.

```
private String userName = "default";

authService.retrieveUserData(new AsyncCallback<UserData>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UserData result) {
            userName = result.getUserName();
            shell.setError("The userName is " + userName + "!");
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            //I've checked and it is not failing.
        }
    });

shell.getLoginWidget().setUserName(userName);
```

shell is a Composite that is added to my RootLayoutPanel. It contains a DivElement of which the InnerText is set by shell.setError(String). shell also has a LoginWidget with a SpanElement of which the InnerText is set by shell.getLoginWidget().setUserName(String). userName is obviously a String that is initialized to "default".

The problem is that the shell.setError("The userName is " + userName + "!"); (inside the AsyncCallback) sets the InnerText to whoever is currently logged in. BUT shell.getLoginWidget().setUserName(userName); (outside the AsyncCallback) sets the InnerText to "default".

I have tried so many different things and they all seem to have the same scope problem. What really confuses me is that [this](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/appengine.html) example shows almost exactly the same technique for saving the result of the RPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT RPC methods are [asynchronous](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideGettingUsedToAsyncCalls) - their return values are not available immediately. The flow of control for the code you posted is as follows:

1. Set `userName` to "default".
2. Ask the `authService` for the `UserData`. This fires off an asynchronous `XMLHttpRequest` for the `UserData.
3. Set the `userName` in the login widget to the current value of `userName`, which is "default".
4. Some time later the asynchronous request initiated in step 2 will return at which point the `userName` variable will be set to the returned value.

The correct thing to do is to set the user name in the `onSuccess` method of the `AsyncCallback`:

```
public void onSuccess(UserData result) {
  userName = result.getUserName();
  shell.getLoginWidget().setUserName(userName);
}
```